# nginx config for same server but different ports

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I recently upgraded from nginx `1.9.2` to `1.14.0` and something that worked in our old configuration is no longer working. I have our normal website on standard SSL configuration, but I also have an `http` version running with the same domain name but on port `8888` (let's call this the alternate site). The sample configuration below no longer works, it results in my alternate site being redirected to https (but still on port 8888).

What is even more strange is that if I open a private browsing window, and go directly to the alternate url (`http://my_domain.com:8888`) it will work. But the moment I browse to our normal `https` site, the alternate site has this issue.

The relevant portion of my `nginx.conf` is below. Does anyone see what the issue might be?

```
# Configuration for "alternate" website
server {
  listen <ip>:8888;
  server_name my_domain.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8889
    ...
  }
}

# Redirect normal http traffic (port 80) to https
server {
  listen <ip>:80;
  server_name my_domain.com;
  return 301 https://my_domain.com$request_uri;
}

# Configuration for standard https site
server {
  listen <ip>:443 ssl http2;
  server_name my_domain.com;
  ... SSL configuration ...
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:127.0.0.1:12345;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the `<ip>` in the `listen` directive. But, the service on 8889 is probably the source of the redirect.